# Add attributes for UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ibinspectable

I'm developing a custom class.
The goal is user will add a `UITableViewController` to the storyboard and set its class to mine.
and my class will fill the `tableView`.

Here's my question: I want to give the user to set some attributes like header color, etc in storyboard, but `@IBdesignable` can't be used for `UITableViewController`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to subclass a `UITableView` instead of `UITableViewController`.

Comment: My library will have some other view controllers. maybe the best approach is if user want to change some attributes he subclass my class and set that for UITableViewController class

Comment: You can also use a UITableViewController and a protocol to oblige user to implements variables or method. For example a method which return the header background color.

Comment: Huh!?  Why do you need to subclass UITableView?